# How to match two sets of data over 1 or more identifier, of unequal length?

Tags: programming, sql

Brief Question about how to best match lists with Criteria from Identifiers (thus for me: translate SQL to Mathematica ;) ).

If I have two sets:

```
 set1 = {{ExperimentCode1, 
  No of Experiments1}, {ExperimentCode2, No of Experiments2} ...}  
 set2 = {{ExperimentCode1, 
   TypeofExp1}, {ExperimentCode2, No of TypeofExp1} ...}
```

Now set 1 has 10 Entries, set2 only contains data for 3.

```
'Sql: Select * from set1 Inner Join set 2 on set1.Experimentcode=set2.Experimentcode'
```

This only matches cases in SQL where the variables exist in both lists (Thus result = 3 Elements)

```
'Sql: Select * from set1 Left Join set 2 on set1.Experimentcode=set2.Experimentcode'
```

This returns all Elements from List 1 and the matched from List 2 (result=10 elements, 3 Elements have now the additional value type, the other 7 Null values for type).

I think this is even more tricky when there is more than one Identifier (Thus two fields together represent a unique identfying number).

Comment: Why not use the Mma `DatabaseLink` package(http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/DatabaseLink/tutorial/Overview.html) and `SQLExecute` to execute any SQL command directly.

Comment: yes i tried it, the thing is the data I need to access are saved in a Access Database.. somehow I couldn't establish a link to the ms access directly...

Comment: Access access (hoho) can be tricky, especially with 64bit systems. On a Win XP 32bit system I had no difficulties (worked as advertised, at least for reading). You just have to get the whole ODBC/DSN registration mumbo jumbo right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know sql and the formats for `set1` and `set2` are somewhat unclear to me so I could be completely missing the point but maybe you could do something like this for the Inner Join query

```
intersect[set1_, set2_] := Module[{expCodes},
  expCodes = Intersection[set2[[All, 1]], set1[[All,1]]];
  Reap[Sow[#2, #1] & @@@ set1;
     Sow[#2, #1] & @@@ set2, expCodes, Flatten[{#1, #2}, 1] &][[2, 
     All, 1]]]
```

and this for the Left Join query

```
join[set1_, set2_] := Module[{expCodes},
  expCodes = set1[[All, 1]];
  PadRight[Reap[Sow[#2, #1] & @@@ set1;
     Sow[#2, #1] & @@@ set2, expCodes, Flatten[{#1, #2}, 1] &][[2, 
     All, 1]],
   Automatic, Null]]
```

Example data:

```
set1 = Table[{i, RandomInteger[10, 3]}, {i, 10}]
set2 = Table[{i, "Type " <> ToString[i]}, {i, RandomSample[Range[10], 3]}]
```

> ```
> {{1, {9, 0, 4}}, {2, {3, 9, 4}}, {3, {9, 2, 5}}, {4, {1, 10, 5}}, 
>    {5, {6, 4, 6}}, {6, {2, 1, 4}}, {7, {6, 5, 6}}, {8, {7, 3, 1}}, 
>    {9, {9, 4, 9}}, {10, {6, 6, 2}}}
>
> {{5, "Type 5"}, {3, "Type 3"}, {7, "Type 7"}}
> ```

Then `intersect` gives

```
intersect[set1, set2]
```

> ```
> {{3, {9, 2, 5}, "Type 3"}, {5, {6, 4, 6}, "Type 5"}, {7, {6, 5, 6}, "Type 7"}}
> ```

and `join`

```
join[set1, set2]
```

> ```
> {{1, {9, 0, 4}, Null}, {2, {3, 9, 4}, Null}, {3, {9, 2, 5}, "Type 3"}, 
>    {4, {1, 10, 5}, Null}, {5, {6, 4, 6}, "Type 5"}, {6, {2, 1, 4}, Null}, 
>    {7, {6, 5, 6}, "Type 7"}, {8, {7, 3, 1}, Null}, {9, {9, 4, 9}, Null}, 
>    {10, {6, 6, 2}, Null}}
> ```

This should be expandable to selection on multiple columns by adjusting the definition of `expCodes` in the definitions of `intersect` and `join`.